# how to use VBA to batch adjustment resource graphs in MS project custom reports

Tags: vba, ms-project

I have created custom report in my project so I can see resource graphs for the duration of the project. [here is the sample of my graphs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOPtA.png)
considering that there are many charts/graphs in my project, I want to create a VBA code to adjust x axis (dates) so it updates based on "project status date".

---> if I had to do this manually this is where I need to adjust
[shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFa80.png)

**my problem:** I can't locate which property I need to change in order to fix this.
so far I have tried methods and properties on "***shape***" and "***chart***" objects but with no avail.

```
Sub AdjustChartDates()
Dim myReport As Report
Dim myShape As Shape
Dim myChart As Chart
Dim seriesInChart As SeriesCollection
Dim chartSeries As Series

Set myReport = ActiveProject.Reports(8)  'target report is index8
Set myShape = myReport.Shapes(4) 'this is index of one of the charts
Set myChart = myShape.Chart
Set seriesInChart = myChart.SeriesCollection
```

'what do I need to write here?

```
end sub
```

thanks!

Comment: This appears to be another example of the incompleteness of Project's API. The [SeriesCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.seriescollection) object has no real properties or methods. If in fact there are no useful methods or properties on any of the report objects, the only way that comes to mind is to use windows api calls like FindWindow, SendMessage, etc to automate the user interface.